# conda: команда не найдена

Tags: ubuntu, anaconda, conda

Необходимо установить seaborn:

```
conda install -c anaconda seaborn
```

В ответ:

> conda: команда не найдена

Кто-нибудь может доступно объяснить, как установить путь к файлу, используя `export PATH`?

Comment: Какая система (Windows/Linux ?), установлена ли anaconda?

Comment: @insolor стоит Ubuntu 18.04.2, да, anaconda установлена